# how load model in another modules in hmvc in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, model

I want to use The Modular Extensions HMVC in my Project like this:

```
modules  
      module01
            models
                models01.php
            controllers
                controller01.php
            views
                views01.php
      module02
            models
                models01.php
            controllers
                controller01.php
            views
                views01.php
      ‘
      ‘
```

and i want use 'models01.php' from `module01` , is there any way?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
$this->load->model("module01/models01");
```

You can call any models from any module like this. Tested.

Comment: how can I rename that loaded model with another name?

Comment: @MostafaShahverdy, Try this $this->load->model("module01/models01", "new_name"); I didn't tried.

Comment: It seems that I have some problems with my path and namings

Comment: while naming models, always try to add model as suffix. 
eg : Somename_model

Answer (score 0):

add module name followed by model name, make sure every word is in small.
I resolved my issue by using this piece of code.

```
$this->load->model('settings/settings_model','settings_model');
```

Answer (score 0):

**In my case using `$this->load->model("module01/models01");` not worked**,

But after debugging for couple of hours i have found the solution which is as below, i will explain it using the same example as Questioner:

So the solution **not working in my case because i have module name as `Module01` (first letter was capital in my directory name)** and even if i use the same while loading model like `$this->load->model("Module01/models01");` it wasn't working.

Then after trying lots of different cases i have found the solution that worked and want to **share some of the rule which we have to follow if we are working in hmvc in codeigniter and loading multiple models in one controller** which are as follows:

- **Names of the Directories in `modules` folder must be in lowercase** (should be like **`module01`** not <strike>**`Module01`**</strike>.)
- **The 1<sup>st</sup> letter of the controller and model files name have to be the uppercase** like `Module01 and Models01`(see below example).
- The 1<sup>st</sup> letter of the **class name of the controller and model must be in uppercase** like

  ```
  // module01/Module01.php
  class Module01 extends MX_Controller {
     //some code
  }

  // module01/Models01.php
  class Models01 extends CI_Model {
     //some code
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->model('module/Modelname','alise');
```

Remember 1st Letter should be Capital for the Model Name

```
$this->load->model("module01/Models01",'models01');
$this->models01->function_name();
```

Comment: you should do code formatting as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting